# Selectively replace line breaks in a string (python)

Tags: python, string, replace

I've already read different Q/A here, but couldn't find my solution.
I have some messy long texts and need to replace the line breaks in it with white spaces, only when it is in the middle of a sentence (not when after "." or "!" or "?")
ex :

```
"this line break must stay.  
but this one  
not."
```

output must be :

```
"this line break must stay.  
but this one not."
```

Comment: The input and the output seems to be the same.

Comment: Ok, thank you ! I'm new here and I didn't know about the two spaces for line break in the question editor ... I seem to have many problems with line breaks : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with negative lookbehind. Here's a regex tutorial that I refer to when I'm not sure about some usage:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

```
import re
p = re.compile('(?<![.!?])\n')
text = "hello,\nMy name is Hal.\nHow are\nyou doing?\n"
re.sub(p, ' ', text)
# outputs:
'hello, My name is Hal.\nHow are you doing?\n'
```

How it works:

`?<!` is the negative lookbehind. (`?<=` is the positive lookbehind). A negative lookbehind will *not* match a pattern if it follows the lookbehind pattern.

In this case, the matching pattern in `\n`, and the lookbehind pattern it must not match are `?`, `.` or `!`

Comment: Interesting approach. What if you replaced `(\?|\!|\.)` with `[.?!]` to make it a bit more readable?

Comment: Nice, thank you ! I'll try it now. It looks like I'll have to adapt it, but you gave me the direction, thanks.

Comment: there is no need here, i had it in the code as i was copy-pasted from another snippet I was working on

Comment: I don't understand. I was trying to adapt it and it didn't work in my code, so to be sure I tried it in a new clean .py file, copy/pasting your code and just adding print(text) in the end. Doesn't work. Still has 4 line breaks. I am working in Pycharm on python 3. What's my trouble here ?

Comment: are you saying that the example snippet that i posted doesn't work on your end? or the snippet works but you're unable to adapt it to your code?